# Defining functions on enumeration types in Z3

Tags: z3, smt

I have an enumeration type *BoolT* that contains *Bool* and *Bot*

```
(declare-datatypes () ((BoolT Bool Bot)))
```

and I want to define an equality function *eq* that given two *BoolT* returns *Bot* if one of the arguments is *Bot*, otherwise the equality between the two *Bool* arguments. However, I am not able to define the actual comparison between the boolean values. Until now I get the function

```
(define-fun eq ((x1 BoolT) (x2 BoolT)) BoolT
    (ite (or (= x1 Bot) (= x2 Bot)) Bot Bool))
```

while I need something like

```
(define-fun eq ((x1 BoolT) (x2 BoolT)) BoolT
    (ite (or (= x1 Bot) (= x2 Bot)) Bot 
           (or (and (= x1 true)(= x2 true)) (and (= x1 false)(= x2 false)))
)
```

or at least a correct definition of the following predicate

```
(define-fun is-True ((x1 BoolT)) Bool 
     (ite (= x1 true) true false)
)
```

Is there a way to model the *eq* function or the previous predicate on *BoolT*?

Answer (score 0):

You will need tagged unions in Z3, similar to ML data-types. You can't just take the union of an existing type and included it in a datatype declaration.
So you will need to write something like:

```
   (declare-datatypes () ((BoolT True False Bot)))
```

or

```
   (declare-datatypes () ((BoolT (mkB (tf B)) Bot) (B True False)))
```

Then you can write:

```
 (define-fun is-True1 ((x BoolT)) Bool 
    (= (mkB True) x))
```

or

```
 (define-fun is-True2 ((x BoolT)) Bool 
 (and (is-mkB x) (= True (tf x))))
```

and assert

```
 (declare-const a BoolT)
 (assert (is-True2 a))
```

Declaring (B True False) 
automatically declares predicates is-True and is-False

```
 (declare-const b B)
 (assert (is-True b))
```

Comment: Thanks Nikolaj! Therefore, as I need to specify *true* and *false* separately, this means that I cannot use this approach also to extend *Int* with the same value *Bot*. Isn't it?